# caching gifs in flutter

Tags: flutter, caching

i have 500 gifs and need to store them on internet and copy their links then put all of them in the app as a result it can be displayed on the screen, i have 2 questions, first one is i need a place where i can put my gifs on internet that can handle the huge GB transferred bandwidth due to many people who will access the gifs on the app,

second question is how can i cache the gif for the first time when the user display it on the app ? because if he accesses too much without caching (save the gif in device) then the bandwidth will be too much

how can i edit this code to cache the gif for the first time he sees it ?

```
Container(
              height: 350,
              width: 350,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage('the link of the gif'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

also is there a way to reduce the amount of bandwidth ?

Comment: is the list of 500 GIFs constant? Like all users will use all 500.

Comment: i'm putting the worst scenario that maybe all users see all the gifs so the bandwidth of gb transferred will be huge and as the time goes, the users will be increased and the more users access those gifs, the bandwidth will be consumed very quickly so i need to handle this issue

Comment: Okay, I'm a frontend developer so I will not know much about backend but as far as i know, every time users request for the files ( API call that returns the list) they will receive only urls not the files... All files will be downloaded on users device as per your code there after. So I don't see how the bandwidth would be huge.. Correct me if I'm missing something :)

Comment: i have already made a test with firebase, i stored my gifs there then i accessed only 1 gif in my app, after that, i saw the usage of the bandwidth that i had made for only this 1 gif and it was the same size as the gif (it was around 150kb) , i restarted my app then i accessed the same gif to see if it will consume another 150kb or not, and yes it consumed it so the total of the bandwidth was 300kb+, imagine 1000 persons or even higher accessed many gifs so it will be insane huge

Comment: agreed. That seems to be out of my scope then.. As for caching the GIFs on device, you can download all or on demand and store it on device cache or local storage. So  each user only accesses it once. There are many packages that provide this feature, you can check, my suggestion use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager

Answer (score 1):

To cache your images you can use the CachedNetworkImage widget:

https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image

To reduce the bandwidth you can try to compress the images.